# Use size constraint with Integer in Grails

Tags: validation, grails, constraints, grails-orm

The reference doc says that the size constraint:

> Uses a Groovy range to restrict the size of a collection or number or
>   the length of a String.

When I put a size constraint on an integer, I get a warning

> Property [prop] of domain class  TheClass has type
>   [java.lang.Integer] and doesn't support constraint [size]. This
>   constraint will not be checked during validation.

Is the doc wrong?

I know I could use range but it would generally be easier to be able to specify the amount of digits in the number rather than the actual value (like a social security number must have 7 digits or whatever it is, rather than making a range of 1000000 - 9999999).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the number of digits, make sure it's positive and has a certain length:

```
myInteger( validator: {
   return it > 0 &&  (it.toString.length) == 7
})
```

Comment: was the `return` necessary?

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer whilst searching JIRA: http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GRAILS-947. The doc is wrong.

> We don't need minSize, maxSize and size constraints for numeric fields
>   anymore since this functionality is on min, max and range constraints
>   respective. So we marking these constraints (for numeric fields only)
>   as deprecated in 0.5 and will remove it in 0.6.

Looks like it's up to the custom validator.

Comment: "remove it in 0.6" As of 2.1.1, this is still in there.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use max to constrain an integer like myIntProp(max:9999999)

Comment: That would just be like using a range. It would generally be easier to be able to specify the amount of digits in the number rather than the actual value (like a social security number must have 7 digits or whatever it is, rather than making a range of 1000000 - 9999999).

Comment: It would be easier if it were possible, but I don't see how a custom validator is easier than either a range or max.  Another thing to consider is that if you are working with "numbers" like SSN or US zip codes that can contain leading zeros, it might be better to use a String anyway.  Just a thought. -- Dave

Comment: Well there's room for error when you type 7 0's in a row, that's all. Nevertheless I will probably settle for this rather than the custom validator I think. The String point is valid... but I think it's all around easier to use a number, and just format it to display a certain amount of digits (i.e. include leading zeros).

Answer (score 0):

As you pointed out in your [Jira](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GRAILS-947) link, I think the correct answer for this is to use the [range](http://grails.org/doc/2.2.1/ref/Constraints/range.html) constraint for Integers.

I think this is a simple as replacing `size` with `range`.